# How to grab the keys and value from an array in an array with php

Tags: php, arrays

`print_r($top5)` gives me an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [title1] => Array ( 
                [id_1] => 4 
                )
    [title2] => Array ( 
                [id_2] => 5 
                ) 
    [title3] => Array ( 
                [id_3] => 8 
                ) 
    [title4] => Array ( 
                [id_4] => 3 
                ) 
    [title5] => Array ( 
                [id_5] => 2 
                ) 
    )
```

I want to produce an output in a foreach loop where i need all the values of this array:

```
<a href="page=?"<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $title.' '.$number; ?>
```

`$top5` is the array and when i use a foreach like below:

```
foreach($top5 as $key => $val) {
    echo $key // outputs the name of title
    echo $val // outputs nothing;
             // i need to output the id and number as well, belonging to each title

}
```

Comment: __Do not__ ask several questions in one.

Comment: Why do your arrays have completely different "id" names? Those should at the very least all be `id`, not `id_1`, `id_2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions to get those if there is only one element or if it will always be the first one:

```
foreach($top5 as $key => $val) {
    echo $key;
    echo key($val);
    echo current($val);  //can also use reset()
}
```

You could also use the id key:

```
foreach($top5 as $key => $val) {
    echo $key;
    echo $id = key($val);
    echo $val[$id];
}
```

Comment: Nice, `key` didn't occur to me

Comment: Super. Works perfect!

Comment: any idea how i can sort the array based on the **numbers** in descending order? `rsort($top5)` is not the solution...

Comment: That's another question.  Make sure to but a `var_export` of the array in it to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, either by array pointer or get key by first key:

```
   foreach($top5 as $title => $ids) {
       echo $title;
       echo current($ids); // By array pointer
       echo $ids[array_keys($ids)[0]]; // By first key
   }
```